# Trying to implement Kendo Multi Grid in AngularJS with Array as datasource

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

UI`<select kendo-multi-select k-options="selectOptions" k-ng-model="selectedIds"></select>`
Controller
`$scope.selectOptions = {
    placeholder: "Select products...",
    dataTextField://cannot understand what to put in here,
    valuePrimitive: true,
    autoBind: false,
}`
I have an array of strings as follows;
`$scope.arrayOfStrings = ["abc", "def", "ghi","jkl"];`
I want these strings to be as my options.

Please be specific to the answers, as I am new to angular. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the k-data-source attribute to specify the data source of the multiselect. You should also omit dataTextField in this case:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
   <select kendo-multi-select k-options="selectOptions" k-ng-model="selectedIds" k-data-source="arrayOfStrings"></select>
   <p ng-show="selectedIds.length" style="padding-top: 1em;">Selected: {{ selectedIds }}</p>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives" ])
    .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
      $scope.arrayOfStrings = ["abc", "def", "ghi","jkl"];
        $scope.selectOptions = {
            placeholder: "Select products...",
            valuePrimitive: true,
            autoBind: false,
        };
        $scope.selectedIds = [ "abc", "def" ];
      })
</script>
```

Here is a live demo: http://dojo.telerik.com/@korchev/EMaji

Comment: Thank you so much. It was a great help. Also, Can you help me with letting me know how to find the length of the selectedIds. I tried: In my controller: $scope.arrayOfStrings = ["abc", "def", "ghi","jkl"]; if($scope.selectedIds.length ==3){console.log($scope.selectedIds)} 
        $scope.selectOptions = {
            placeholder: "Select products...",
            valuePrimitive: true,
            autoBind: false,
        };
        $scope.selectedIds = [  ];I basically want to allow a user to select only 3 options ()and want to send the selected options to another API.

Comment: Allowing the user to select only 3 options is done using maxSelectedItems: 3. I want the array of selected options, once the user selects 3 options forever. Thanks in advance